# Adjusting brake pads

Tags: brakes, adjustment

When I use the adjustment screw to adjust how far the pads are away from the rim,
neither side moves the pad.

Is there a fix?

[image]

Comment: I see a couple problems from your pic.  First, it appears you have TWO noodles (curved metal piece) stacked, coming into your brake caliper. There should only be one---the end of that upper, shinier noodle should slip into the silver metal stop of the caliper, then the inner cable continues across to the other side and the pinch bolt. Next, the adjusting screw you've circled is wound way out.  It probably isn't touching the spring and thus has no effect. While your inner cable is loose, turn that screw almost all the way in on both sides of the calipers.

Comment: Keep in mind that these screws are used to balance the pads in relation to the rim and manipulating one side's screw affects both side's lever arms and pad distance to the rim. When everything is hooked up (cable is in all the housing stops and the inner wire is secure in the pinch bolt, you may find that one pad is much closer to the rim than it's opposite, which sets much further from the rim.  To correct this, the screws like you've circled are turned  and this changes the pad to rim distance.  For example, say the left pad is nearly touching the rim...

Comment: To correct/balance the pads you can either tighten the left side's screw which will cause the left pad to move away from the rim AND the right pad to draw closer to the rim due to the cable connection.  If the left screw is turned fully in but more correction is needed, you could go to the right side screw and loosen it, which causes the right side to draw closer to rim and the left side to move away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brake pads on this kind of brake (V-brake) are adjusted with the screw above the one you've circled. The screw at the end of the pad adjust the positioning of the pad relative to the rim. It's one of the jobs where you ideally need 4 to 6 hands to get it right.

The screw that you circled adjusts the symmetry of the pull, or the timing of the pads touching the rim by adjusting the tension of the springs in the pivots.

Comment: I found that the screw I circled adjusted the pad in relation to how close it is to the rim. One pad was very unevenly worn. Used my bench grinder to even it out. Had no luck changing the position of those "cups".@Carel